# WillCascadeOnDelete doesn't establish cascade delete on database

Tags: entity-framework

I don't know if I'm missing something obvious. We're using Entity Framework 6.0.0-rc1 in a project where the model is set up with the fluent API. Configuration of one of our entities could be:

```
HasMany(t => t.Entity)
 .WithRequired(tc => tc.ParentEntity)
 .HasForeignKey(tc => new {tc.Key1, tc.Key2})
 .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

When running this configuration, database gets created correctly, with all tables and fields. Even relationships are correctly established but not the delete cascade.

If I go to Management Studio and I inspect update/delete rules of the relationship, both are deactivated.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but EF6 is stable now - you should update past the RC version.

Comment: It is not clear whether what type the first `HasMany` is called on,  can you clarify that? And can you show us the code generated in the `Up()` method of the migration?

Answer (score 2):

With these classes:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Configured like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
        .HasMany(p => p.Children)
        .WithRequired(c => c.Parent)
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentID)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

}
```

Puts cascade delete on the foreign key:

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.Children",
        c => new
            {
                ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                ParentID = c.Int(nullable: false),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Parents", t => t.ParentID, cascadeDelete: true)
        .Index(t => t.ParentID);

    CreateTable(
        "dbo.Parents",
        c => new
            {
                ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID);

}
```